# How to adjust the gap between the marker and its coordinates in Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I would like to change the margin between the center of the marker and its coordinate. For example, I want the marker's center to be the same place as its coordinates (just like the marker "My Location"). I tried to Google but all I got is a marker floating above its coordinates.

[image]

Comment: What does this have to o with vuejs? And do you have any code that you could share?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Just add an anchor to the icon object with the values equal to half of the scaled sizes, then the marker's center will be the same as its coordinates.

```
var markerIcon = {
    url: markerImage,
    scaledSize: {width: 32, height: 32},
    labelOrigin: {x: 16, y: -10},
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
  }
```

Reference:
https://codinginfinite.com/realtime-moving-cars-google-maps-javascript-firebase/